# webapp2 behaviour replicated in apache/php

Tags: php, python, apache2, webapp2

In webapp2 (python) you can map urls to classes in one file.

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', pgMain), ('/test/', pgTest)], debug=True)
```

How would I setup such a thing in php & apache?

Thanks

EDIT:

What I am after is everything after a foldername to be redirected to a file in that folder. eg.

```
/version/1.0/test/folder/ => /version/1.0/index.php & var="/test/folder"
/version/1.0/another/     => /version/1.0/index.php & var="/another"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way for doing this is to create .htaccess file in your app folder and put this code there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,NS,L]
```

Please note that you need to modify "RewriteBase" directive and put path of your application there "/" means your document root.

After creating .htacess file all requests will be routed to your index.php file and you can access URI via PHP's super global variable $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: @loseb doesn't recognize folders eg. /x/ in the url. errorlog states File does not exist: {website root}/var

Comment: I use this very configuration for several projets and it's definitely correct. Did you modify RewriteBase according to your app path and could you please make sure if "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" line exists in Apache's httpd.conf file?

Comment: @loseb mod_rewrite loaded. Webpage shows "The requested URL {website root}/0.1.0/index.php was not found on this server." Log shows "File does not exist: {website root}/var". What is 'var'?

Comment: Can you check DocumentRoot variable in httpd.conf?

P.S. 
I do not have idea what "var" is

Comment: @loseb ah! got it. the Rewritebase is relative to the website root, not the absolute path. Thanks